# Does Coverity support Interprocedural-Analysis

Tags: coverity

Program execute result:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  ./test.out
```

Coverity analyse output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// uaf
void test_1(void *p) {
    free(p);
     CID 358676: Read from pointer after free (USE_AFTER_FREE) [select issue]
    printf("%x\n", *((int *)p));
}

// loop write
void test_2(int total, char *p) {
    char a[100];

    for(int i=0;i < total; i++) {
        a[i] = *(p + i);
    }
}

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
}Person;
// uint8 *p
void test_3(Person *p) {
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)p;

    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(Person) + 100; i++) {
        *ptr = 'a';
    }

    free(p);
     CID 358686: Read from pointer after free (USE_AFTER_FREE) [select issue]
    printf("%x\n", *((int *)p));
}

// state machine
enum {
    S_START,
    S_IDLE,
    S_BUSY,
    S_UNKNOWN
};
int gState = S_START;
void *gPtr = NULL;

void handle_start() {
    int size;

    printf("input malloc size:\n");
     CID 358721: Unchecked return value from library (CHECKED_RETURN) [select issue]
    scanf("%d", &size);

     CID 134591: Untrusted allocation size (TAINTED_SCALAR) [select issue]
    gPtr = malloc(size);

    gState = S_BUSY;
    printf("S_START -> S_BUSY\n");
}

void handle_busy() {
    char buff[100];

    printf("input string:\n");
     CID 358720: Unchecked return value from library (CHECKED_RETURN) [select issue]
     CID 358719: Calling risky function (DC.STREAM_BUFFER) [select issue]
    scanf("%s", buff);

    strcpy(gPtr, buff);
    puts(gPtr);
    gState = S_IDLE;
    printf("S_BUSY -> S_IDLE\n");
}

void handle_idle(void *p) {
    char cmd;
    
    printf("continue or exit(C/E)?");
     CID 358718: Unchecked return value from library (CHECKED_RETURN) [select issue]
    scanf("%c", &cmd);

    if (cmd == 'c' || cmd == 'C') {
        gState = S_BUSY;
        printf("S_IDLE -> S_BUSY\n");
    } else {
        free(p);
        printf("S_IDLE -> S_START\n");
        printf("exit\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void process(void *p) {
    switch (gState) {
        case S_START:
            handle_idle(p);
            handle_start();
            break;
        case S_BUSY:
            handle_busy();
            break;
        case S_IDLE:
            handle_idle(p);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void test_4(void *p) {
    while (1)
    {
        process(p);
    }
}

void test_5(void *pData) {
    int kind = 0;
    void *ptr = NULL;

    printf("input kind:\n");
     CID 358724: Unchecked return value from library (CHECKED_RETURN) [select issue]
    scanf("%d", &kind);

 1. Switch case default.
    switch (kind) {
        case 1:
            ptr = malloc(100);
            break;
        case 2:
            ptr = malloc(200);
            break;
        default:
 2. alloc_fn: Storage is returned from allocation function malloc.
 3. var_assign: Assigning: ptr = storage returned from malloc(64UL).
            ptr = malloc(64);
 4. Breaking from switch.
            break;
    }

 5. Switch case default.
    switch(kind) {
        case 1:
            memcpy(ptr, pData, 1000);
            break;
        case 2:
            memcpy(ptr, pData, 2000);
            break;
        default:
 6. noescape: Resource ptr is not freed or pointed-to in memcpy.
            memcpy(ptr, pData, 64);
 7. Breaking from switch.
            break;
    }

 8. noescape: Resource (char *)ptr is not freed or pointed-to in printf.
    printf("result: %s\n", (char *)ptr);
 
 CID 358723 (#1-3 of 3): Resource leak (RESOURCE_LEAK)
 9. leaked_storage: Variable ptr going out of scope leaks the storage it points to.
}

void test_6_sub(void *p) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    free(p);
}

void test_6(void *p) {
    test_6_sub(p);
}

int *n() { 
    return 0; 
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    // int a; 

    // printf("input copy length: ");
    // scanf("%d",&a); 
    // printf("copy %d bytes\n",a);
    
    // void *p = malloc(100);
    // memcpy(p, (char *)&a, a);

    // printf("%s", (char *)&a);
    gPtr = malloc(100);
    char *p = gPtr;
    free(gPtr);
    char *name = "adfsasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";
    // test_4(p);

    // test_6(p);

    return *(n());
}
```

After analyse by coverity, I just do not get the vulnerability infomation what I want.
According to the introduction of Coverity

- should be find the free of Null pointer vulnerability.
- should be find the dead code
- should be find the function call chains

But I got nothing
Is something wrong?
I got this test result at https://scan.coverity.com
Is the online service has some restrict?

Comment: Here is two question: 1. as I do not call test_1(), coverity find the vunerability in this function; 2. in main() call test_5(), but coverity can not find the vunerability in test_5(), there are some obvious vunerability

Comment: I have tried modify the code, call test_4() in main(), but still nothing found. There is a Null Pointer free vunerability in the call chain at handle_idle(). How can I test the interprocedural-analysis feature of coverity?

Comment: I did what you suggest, I created a complete program, contain the bug which can cause crash. Compile and run, make sure the bug did exist, submit to coverity. still got nothing what I want. except some secondary alerts from Coverity

Comment: ./test.out  
continue or exit(C/E)?s  
test.out(1754,0x106a4a600) malloc: *** error for object 0x6000003c0000: pointer being freed was not allocated  
test.out(1754,0x106a4a600) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug  
zsh: abort      ./test.out

Comment: Alright, now edit your question to include the new test program (either in addition to or instead of the existing code; I lean toward replacement) and show the Coverity output you got for that code (maybe a screenshot?).  Then it might be possible to explain why the output does not contain what you want.

Comment: My question has updated, with new code, program execute result and coverity analyse result. I want to find the free Null Pointer vunerability, call chaint is: main() -> test_4() -> process() -> handle_idle() -> free(gPtr)

Comment: My reputation is 1, the system not allow post picture, so I use text instead

Comment: I see now which bug you were after (I was misled by the presence of `test_1`, `test_2`, etc.), and have attempted to answer accordingly.  I suggest editing the question to include the clarification: "I want to find the free Null Pointer vunerability, call chaint is: main() -> test_4() -> process() -> handle_idle() -> free(gPtr)".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the title, "Does Coverity support Interprocedural-Analysis", is **yes**.  The Coverity analysis indeed examines how functions call one another in an attempt to discover inconsistencies.

However, there are limitations to the precision of that interprocedural analysis.  In particular, although it tries to keep track of relationships involving (at least) parameters, return values, and things pointed to by those, in most cases it cannot track relationships between global variables across function calls.  (The reason for that is there are simply too many such variables and too many potential relationships, so trying to track them all would result in the analysis never terminating.)

In your example, there is an intended invariant that `gPtr` is a valid pointer if and only if `gState == S_IDLE`.  Consequently, the `handle_idle()` function can only be called when `gState == S_IDLE`. The `process()` function violates that requirement by calling `handle_idle()` while `gState == S_START`, which (based on the clarification in the comments) is the bug you want to find.  That deduction is unfortunately beyond the capabilities of the tool, so it does not report it.

Comment: I already noticed the global variable reason, so I modify the code, pass the pointer as a parameter, but still nothing found. I will update the code and Coverity output in my question.

Comment: code updated in my question finished

Comment: As you can see, I add test_6() function code, when I use test_6() to replace test_4() in main(), still nothing found, but a Use-After-Free defect, the Double Free defect not find by Coverity

Comment: Could you show me an example, include a defect with `Interprocedural-Analysis` feature that Coverity can find

Comment: @Duallay Try this: `int *n() { return 0; } int main() { return *(n()); }`.

Comment: Use your suggestion, I modify the code, update the program run result and Coverity output. Coverity does not find the defect in the code that you gave.

Comment: Is the online version of Coverity has some capability limitation? Or I do not use Coverity in the right way

Comment: @Duallay I'm not aware of any limitation of the online version.  I don't understand why it's not reporting the newly added code.

Comment: @ Scott McPeak Could you leave an email address, MaybeI we can do some business cooperation